# How can I wait for an event to happen before asserting a test in jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an AntD Form with the following event:

```
<Form
    form={form}
    onFieldsChange={(field, allFields) => {
        //return true for each field, that does no longer equal its default value
        const dirtyFields = allFields.filter(fld => {
            return fld.touched
        })
        setIsDirty(dirtyFields.length > 0)
    }}
>
</Form>
```

The rule is, if no field has been touched, the submit button should be disabled. Now if I test this manually, this approach works just fine. However, I am having trouble replicating this in a test.

At this point, this is the test I am having:

```
it('should enable submit button, when any field is touched', async () => {
    act(() => {
        render(<NewEmployeeModal
            visible={true}
            handleClose={() => { }}
        />)
    })

    const input = await screen.getByTestId('employeeLastNameInput')
    expect(input).not.toBeNull()

    await userEvent.type(input, 'SomeRandomLastName', { delay: 20 })

    //now the button should be enabled
    let submitButton = await waitFor(async () => (await screen.findByText("Speichern")).closest('button'))
    expect(submitButton).not.toBeDisabled()
})
```

I am typing in the lastName into the input field, with a delay of 20 milliseconds between each character.
After this, I am retrieving the the submit button and expect it to be enabled.

This is failing, with the following error:

> Tests concerning the touched or dirty state › should enable submit
> button, when any field is touched
>
> ```
> expect(element).not.toBeDisabled()
>
> Received element is disabled:
>   <button class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" disabled="" form="emp-form-new-employee" type="submit" />
>
>   87 |         let submitButton = await waitFor(async () => (await screen.findByText("Speichern")).closest('button'))
>   88 |
> > 89 |         expect(submitButton).not.toBeDisabled()
>      |                                  ^
>   90 |
>   91 |     })
>   92 | })
> ```

It is unclear to me, why the submit button is not enabled at this point. So the question is: why is it not working and how can I improve it, so that it replicates the desired behavior?

Comment: Why don't you include the state expectation in the waitFor? Right now you're only waiting for the button to _exist_. Also note type with a delay is asynchronous.

Comment: my bad  - added `await`. How do I change waiting for the button to exist, to waiting for it to be enabled?

Comment: Have a look at the examples in https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs linked by Jonrsharpe, `findBy` already incorporates `WaitFor`, so all I need to do was:

```
//now the button should be enabled
expect(await screen.findByText("Speichern")).not.toBeDisabled()
```